# Userform listbox with percentages?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I am using a listbox in an userform which displays a unique values from a column which is formatted as percentage. I am generating a unique list/values by using dictionary object and feeding it to a listbox.

My problem is all the values are shown as decimal numbers in listbox not as percentages. Any idea how to show them as percentages/format?.

FYI: listbox values can change depends on the user selection text/numbers/date/currency/percentage

unique list code

```
Sub UniqData(fString As String, cbNr As Integer) ' fString as string
Dim d As Object

With Sheets("xxx")
cNr = WorksheetFunction.Match(fString, .Rows(1), 0)

lRo = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arrD = .Range(.Cells(2, cNr), .Cells(lRo, cNr))
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     For Each c In arrD
            If Len(c) > 0 Then
                d00 = dic.Item(c.Text)
            End If
      Next c
    k = d.keys
End With

UserForm1.Controls("lb" & cbNr).List = k

End Sub
```

like this.

Comment: How do you fill your dictionary? Can you post your code?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a variable a before d.Add a, a so I guess you meant c.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by @Meehow, the use `c.Text` may generate error if the data is too larged to be displayed in the cell!

So, use `Format(c.Value, "0.0%")` as key in the `d.Add` line and you'll have the formatting from the Excel cell :
    Sub UniqData(fString As String, cbNr As Integer) ' fString as string
    Dim d As Object

```
With Sheets("xxx")
    cNr = WorksheetFunction.Match(fString, .Rows(1), 0)

    lRo = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrD = .Range(.Cells(2, cNr), .Cells(lRo, cNr))
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c in arrD
        d.Add Format(c.Value, c.NumberFormat), c.Value
    Next c
    k = d.keys
End With

UserForm1.Controls("lb" & cbNr).List = k

End Sub
```

Comment: shirnk the column's width so text becomes #### and try again ;)

Comment: @Meehow : Indeed, I never thought of that (I never use `.Text` but it popped up in my mind when I answered!) Thx for pointing it out! ;)

Comment: thanks for the answers, i use For Each c In ftArr
                If Len(c) > 0 Then
                    d00 = dic.Item(c.Text)
                End If
            Next c

Comment: sorry guys, i have editied my post. I use ".item ". any idea .tiem(c.text) gives me error.

Comment: Try the last version of the code I posted, and tell me if you've got errors : *which line and which error*. And tell me the *differences between* the result of that code and what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting cells using the spreadsheet only modifies how the number is going to visually present to a user. The underlying value remains unchanged.

Therefore, you need to explicitly format the value to what you want it to look like as you are adding it the dictionary.

```
d.Add Format(c, "0.0%"), c
```